# Azure B2C Migration from Preview to Production tenant Leads to successful login without the Iprincipal being passed back

Tags: azure, adal, azure-ad-b2c

Guys I am not including code ATM because this seems to be a Azure B2C setup question not a coding question.  If needed I will upload it but the code in question is quite a bit to read thru.

Q:  Has anyone successfully migrated from a Azure B2C "Preview" Tenant to a "Production" Tenant?

We had a functioning website using the B2C "Preview" Tenant and Microsoft informed us that we needed to create a "Production" Tenant now that it had been released.  We deleted the "Preview" tenant and created back the "Production" tenant with the same name but when we did that we lost our fallback to the working "Preview" Tenant.  The New "Production" tenant failed to create with the b2c_extensions-app that we had in the "Preview" Tenant which we believe caused it to be not functional.  So we created a second "Production" Tenant with a new name and that did create with the b2c-extensions-apps and we proceeded to change the web apps settings to point to the new name.  Now when we signup the user gets created in the new B2C AD but when Microsoft comes back to our return URL the returned IPrincipal has no claims and the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.  How can a user get created in the B2C  and return you get a User.Identity.IsAuthenticated=false?

Additional Info:  the ID_Token is on the authresp. It is looking like MVC is not decrypting the encrypted token and creating the Iprincipal User.  We are currently using package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version 4.0.2.206221351.  Could it be that the new Production version of B2C AD only works with System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version 5.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it took a month of Microsoft working on it to get a workaround to this and get our website back up and working.  Bottom line: Below is the takeaways from this experience.

1) Do not delete your Preview B2C until you are sure your Production one is 100% working with your website.

2) When creating your production B2C do not use the same name as you did on your Preview B2C.  ( this is a known bug to Microsoft.  Good to know after the fact, Right?)

3) Do not use the same names for your Sign-in, Sign-up, Password-Reset, or Profile-editing policies.  ( this is critical.)

4. You must change the port number you use for testing locally in the Azure B2C Application Reply Url, your web.config ReturnURL variable, and in the projects properties setting.   (This was also critical for us.)

5). Microsoft had us change the calls to OpenIdConnect in the following places:

a) the ida:AadInstance in the web.config to

```
<add key="ida:AadInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={1}"/>
```

b) The modified code in App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.Owin;
namespace WebSite
{
public partial class Startup
{
    // The ACR claim is used to indicate which policy was executed
    public const string AcrClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference";

    // App config settings
    public static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    public static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AadInstance"];
    public static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
    public static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];

    // B2C policy identifiers
    public static string SignUpPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignUpPolicyId"];
    public static string SignInPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignInPolicyId"];
    public static string ProfilePolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:UserProfilePolicyId"];
    public static string ChangePasswordPolicyId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ChangePasswordPolicyId"];

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        // Configure OpenID Connect middleware for each policy
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignUpPolicyId));
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId));
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ProfilePolicyId));
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ChangePasswordPolicyId));
    }

    // Used for avoiding yellow-screen-of-death
    private Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        notification.HandleResponse();
        if (notification.Exception.Message == "access_denied")
        {
            notification.Response.Redirect("/");
        }
        else
        {
            notification.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + notification.Exception.Message);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
    {
        return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant, policy),

            AuthenticationType = policy,

            ClientId = clientId,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
            },
            Scope = "openid",
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                SaveSigninToken = true //important to save the token in boostrapcontext
            },

            ProtocolValidator = new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator { RequireNonce = false }
        };
    }
}
}
```

c) The modified code in Controllers/AccountController.cs (see attached code)

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using System.Security.Claims;
using EMC_Portal_Web.Services.DataAccess;
using EMC_Portal_Web;


namespace WebSite.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        public void SignIn()
        {
            // To execute a policy, you simply need to trigger an OWIN challenge.
            // You can indicate which policy to use by adding it to the AuthenticationProperties using the PolicyKey provided.
            try
            {
                if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {

                    // To execute a policy, you simply need to trigger an OWIN challenge.
                    // You can indicate which policy to use by specifying the policy id as the AuthenticationType
                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = Startup.redirectUri }, Startup.SignInPolicyId);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Error Message: " + ex.Message + " Stack: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        public void SignUp()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {

                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = Startup.redirectUri }, Startup.SignUpPolicyId);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Error Message: " + ex.Message + " Stack: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        public new void Profile()
        {
            try
            {
                if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {

                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = Startup.redirectUri }, Startup.ProfilePolicyId);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Error Message: " + ex.Message + " Stack: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }


        public void ChangePassword()
        {
            try
            {
                if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                        new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = Startup.redirectUri }, Startup.ChangePasswordPolicyId);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Error Message: " + ex.Message + " Stack: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        public ActionResult SignOut()
        {
            try
            {
                if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    IEnumerable<AuthenticationDescription> authTypes = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes();
                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(authTypes.Select(t => t.AuthenticationType).ToArray());
                }
                return Redirect(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["Index"].ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Error Message: " + ex.Message + " Stack: " + ex.StackTrace);
                return Redirect(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["Home"].ToString());
            }
        }        
    }
}
```